# Store HTML data

Tags: html, forms

I created a simple form on my HTML website. Is this the correct way to send user's inputted email address to my inbox? Thanks in advance for your help.

HTML code:

```
        <div class="waitlist">
            <form action="MailThis.to/myemail@gmail.com" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="field" required>
                <button>Join Waitlist</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: The form action is probably incorrect (should it be a URL starting with `https://` or something similar?). Have you written the code for sending an email?

Comment: @Raptor: No, I haven't. I just started learning how to code so I didn't know how to write the code for sending an email. I thought by writing out the form action, it would send the user's email address to my inbox? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Of course not. You will need a mail sending script (e.g. PHP script) and a valid SMTP server for sending out emails.

Comment: @Raptor: if I use https://mailthis.to/documentation.html, do I still need to write the mail sending script? Thanks

Comment: You're right, you can use this free service, but please don't send any security-related emails. Also, you cannot use a custom sender email address, which is not recommended. It's better to setup your own environment.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining this. @Raptor

Comment: If you want to create a form that collects user emails for newsletter / mailing list purpose, you can consider using [mailchimp.com](https://mailchimp.com/help/create-a-sample-newsletter-for-potential-subscribers/)